# Filter json file objects into a separate json file with jq

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

At the moment I'm successfully exporting curl output with JQ into a file with valid json.

The comment is as below:

jsonValues=`<curl command> | jq '.["issues"] | map({key: .key, type: .fields.issuetype.name, typeid: .fields.issuetype.id, status: .fields.status.name, summary: .fields.summary})' > FullClosedIssueList.json`; `

You can see that I'm doing two things with this one command:

- Putting all the results into `jsonValues`.
- Exporting to `FullClosedIssueList.json`.

I find that the `jsonValues` objects are formatted missing `[`, `]` and `,`.

```
{
  "key": "ON-12345",
  "type": "Bug",
  "typeid": "1",
  "status": "Closed",
  "summary": "Some Bug Title"
}
{
  "key": "ON-12346",
  "type": "Bug",
  "typeid": "1",
  "status": "Closed",
  "summary": "Some Other Bug Title"
}
```

Whereas the file output is valid json.

```
[
  {
    "key": "ON-12345",
    "type": "Bug",
    "typeid": "1",
    "status": "Closed",
    "summary": "Some Bug Title"
  },
  {
    "key": "ON-12346",
    "type": "Bug",
    "typeid": "1",
    "status": "Closed",
    "summary": "Some Other Bug Title"
  }
]
```

What command do I need to add to JQ such that the objects passed to the bash variable are valid json?

**EDIT:** This is the same problem as described [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/189)

Comment: are you doing `echo $jsonValues` or `echo "$jsonValues"`? In general, you'll want to always dbl-quote your variables.  Good luck.

Comment: jsonValues will just be set to the output of the CURL command and the string "jsonValues=<curl_command>" will be fed in to jq, which will fail because it is not valid JSON...  

if this is about the JIRA REST API, valid JSON should be returned from a CURL call as described in: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Query+issues#JIRARESTAPIExample-Queryissues-Response

Comment: I'm surprised you have *any* value in that variable. If you want to save to a file **and** capture the output into a variable, use `tee` like this: `output=$( some command | tee filename )` -- $output should have exactly the same content as the file

Comment: @glennjackman even if I do `<FullClosedIssueList.json jq '.[] | select(.typeid=="1")' > ClosedBugsList.json` direct from the command line, I get the same problem. The output file has the following removed: `[`,`]` and `,`.

Comment: you need the "map" command in that too, in which the select command should be enclosed `<FullClosedIssueList.json jq '.[] | map(select(.typeid=="1"))'

Comment: @HansZandbelt, that helps a ton. Giving this another go

Comment: @HansZandbelt, that addresses my issue and is the fix. If you want to put in an answer I'll mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the "map" command in that too, in which the select command should be enclosed:

```
cat FullClosedIssueList.json | jq '.[] | map(select(.typeid=="1"))'
```